# Link article from a module parameter (field modal_article)

Tags: joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

I want to develope a joomla! 2.5 module on which the admin could select an article so that the selected article will be displayed as a link in the frontend. The params of a module are declare in the modulename.xml file, so I want to know if there is a field type like the one that lets you select an article when you create a menu item to show a single article.

here is the xml file

```
<fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_ctfapartados/elements/">
<field  name="" type="article"  default="0" label="MOD_APARTADOS_LINK_ONE_LABEL"
description="MOD_APARTADOS_LINK_ONE_DESC"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for some reasons i am not able to edit the code in my previous answer so here is the revised part of code

```
<fieldset 
     name="request" 
     addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_content/models/fields">
     <field 
           name="article_id"
           type="modal_article"
           label="label"
           required="true"
           description="desc"/>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: After making those changes only a text input is shown. I updated my question to show the changes I made (pretty close to what you suggested I guess)

Comment: have you copied the article.php in your elements folder

Comment: I had misplced the elements directory (I created it under tmpl ) I fixed that but now I get this javascript "error writeDynaList is not defined" and the page doesn't display properly

Comment: i had edited my answer with the code working at my end.
if it still didn't work at your end please put your complete xml code to analyze.

Comment: it worked! thanks for your help. I found another way not as nice as this one but works ok too. if you put the following field in your xml you will get a combobox listing all the articles

Comment: here is the code: <field name="artid" type="sql" default="0" label="Select an article" query="SELECT id, title FROM #__content" key_field="id" value_field="title" />

Answer (score 0):

- create a folder in your module with name "elements"
- copy the file article.php from joomlaroot\administrator\components\com_content\elements
  and place it in your modules elements folder
- then in your xml add these lines

Comment: I have a doubt, where exactly do I have to add those lines in my xml file. What got me confused is that in my xml file I have the tags field not param, but with the same attributes.